# boost dataflow_exception when forked from program

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I recently ported a Qt app to use QTcpSockets instead of the posix directly.  The renderer I'm using has code to launch the view app by forking if it isn't already running.  With my newly refactored app, it seems to work fine if the app is launched before I run my renderer.  However, if I launch the renderer without the view app already running, it will call the fork code and the program will crash usually half-way through the render.

```
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of '
boost::archive::iterators::dataflow_exception'
  what():  attempt to decode a value not in base64 char set
```

Since this exception only gets thrown when the fork() method is used, I'm wondering if it's something in the refactoring?  I also believe it only happens when running the renderer (which launches the viewer app) from inside by Qt app.  When the view app is forked directly from the renderer, I don't see this issue.  I'm not sure what the fork() could be doing that could cause this exception.

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid != -1)
{
    if (!pid)
    {
        // Child process executes the following after forking.
    char arg1[] = "piqsl";
    char arg2[] = "-i";
    char arg3[] = "127.0.0.1";
    char* argv[4] = {arg1, arg2, arg3, NULL};
    // TODO: need to pass verbosity level for logginng
    signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);
    nice(2);
    execvp("piqsl",argv);
...
```

The only difference in the refactored viewer app is it uses QTcpSockets (and a QTcpServer) and now links against libQNetwork.  Is this library causing interference now with boost maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fork() creates an exact copy of the original process including all open file handles. Qt seems to use a few pipes/sockets for internal communication and since these are the *same* pipes/sockets in the forked process, they conflict with the original process.

You'll probably have better luck using exec() instead--to my knowledge, there is no way to safely re-instantiate the QApplication after forking. Alternately it should work if you fork *before* creating the QApplication.